# Spring boot high memory usage after some time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a spring boot app deployed on digital ocean, my current droplet (virtual pc, named as droplet) has 1gb of memory.

My app has some cron jobs that get infos from some APIs and stores on the db, i will explain it:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "50 0 0/12 * * ?")
```

^ this one clean some values from a table

```
@Scheduled(cron = "50 0 0/1 * * ?")
```

^ Same as above but for another table

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
```

^ Have two of this, that  get infos from a API, do some math accounts and then store the results on db.

What i see from the monitoring tools is that my memory usage never goes down it always goes up a litle bit.

It start with 40% of usage about 5 hours ago and now its at 75%.

Theres something that i can do to cleanup the memory usage? Maybe a garbage collection?

Im using mysql, btw

Thanks

-- Edit

I just run visualvm, and the results are the show:

Profiler:
[image: Profiler]

Monitor:
[image: Monitor]

Seems like gc is actually running, so, whats wrong? maybe i need to set max heap at digital ocean?

Comment: what are you running from your cron job? also what type of database are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql, forget to mention. Im running a get to a api, the returning values i do some math accounts based on another values and then save this results on the db. Every minute, about 200 records is updated at the db.

Comment: Mysql, good, you're not using some in memory database (had to make sure). Sounds like a memory leak, I don't think garbage collection will help you. I would carefully check to make sure you're not continuously instantiating something heavy duty/long running every-time one of your cron jobs run.

Comment: Try pasting the code that is actually being invoked on these jobs.

Comment: Hi - I am facing same issue using Cron Job in spring boot. My container started with 120 MB of RAM usage and in 2 hours it is now 140 MB. Can u guide.

Comment: relevant question, still without a definitive solution

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a memory leak of some sort, I'd suggest using a profiling tool (such as the free VisualVM) to run your application and attempt to identify where the memory is leak is coming from.

https://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source/

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your Java app or Database query taking lot of time and storing DB result in java heap space.

You need a better profiling tool which not only tells about the heap usage but also point the code which causes the issue.

I personally like [Appdynamics](https://www.appdynamics.com/) a lot, as it tells problem in all the layer of the code. Also its available for free use for certain usage and provide a SAAS solution and very easy to integrate.

Please have a look at it and let me know if you need more info about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to clean the Entity Manager, as it tries to cache stuff you insert into the database.

```
entityManager.clear();
```

I had the same problem some time ago when I imported a few million records within a few minutes. I had quite similar results in the visualvm.

So after each 10k records I cleared the Entity Manager and the used memory was not increasing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In real word applications resources are valuable for developers and companies to spend some money to increase resources.So, every modern application need background works with minimum memory usage.@Schedule is an expensive annotation for JVM.Instead of using this annotation i recommend to you to use TaskQueues such as Celery and Redis.You can Requeue tasks in Redis and then redis publishes them.It is very useful for big processes and background processes.